# Nitpick - 1 consecutive day

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

What does "1 consecutive" mean? Seriously, you can have 2 consecutive days, but how can a singleton of anything "[follow one after the other in order](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consecutive)", when there is no "other"?
[image: 1 consecutive]

Comment: Why gold plate something when you can go all the way and platinum plate it? ;-)

Comment: @bakoyaro: I'm sorry?

Comment: It is an "edge case" (a special case or boundary case or condition, for mathematicians) that was not taken care of. I would opt to say "5 days total, 1 day current streak" or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the quantity of days you login on site in a row. When you complete 30 you earn a Enthusiast badge. For now you have no days in a row.

The word is just the same problem with "you have 1 messages". It's ugly but not important.

Comment: I know what consecutive is, it's just that "1 consecutive" is ugly. But, as you stated, not important. Hence the nitpicking admission.